# session not working in chrome and working in firefox

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, sessionid

My session is not working in chrome and safari browser and working in firefox. Can anyone explain why this is happening ?

```
 <?php
  session_start();

 $sessionuser=$_SESSION['user'];


 ?>
```

If I `print_r($sessionuser)` it is not working in chrome or safari browsers bu working in firefox

Comment: Buy a good book and read about PHP & *Session*.

Comment: Turn on *cookies* - Settings + Show advance settings + Content Settings + Select Allow local data to be set (recommended).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that, other than your code has parsing errors, that you would have to use `session_start();` before you use `$_SESSION[]`

It might be that you have forgotten an old session cookie in firefox. I think it is possible to check this with firebug.

Also check da5id's answer, it will fix the parsing error.

Comment: dude all thing is ok this is work in firefox and not work in chorme

Comment: Is your code outputting any errors or warnings? Sometimes they are not visible on the returned page. It might also be that you have disabled cookies in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
session_start();

$sessionuser=$_SESSION['user'];

echo $sessionuser;
```

Comment: You have store any value in $_SESSION['user'] ?

Comment: Try this function session_register('user');

Answer (score 0):

try the following. It works on my chrome in LINUX.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = "hithere";
$sessionuser=$_SESSION['user'];
print_r($sessionuser);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your browser cookie. Your session not a set If cookie is disabled. You have to go in browser setting and check cookie setting.

Answer (score 0):

### Just try

In my case I just ***reset chrome browser***

Go to chrome://settings/  then click advanced then reset

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the cookies in your Google Chrome in the Setting.

Privacy and Security -> Cookies and other site data -> See all cookies and site data

Search by the domain name or IP and delete the existing cookies.